# Define an isomorphism between finite boolean ring and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains, ring-isomorphism, boolean-ring

I'm trying to prove any finite boolean ring $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. I know this question is already on this site, but the proofs I saw used the ring's characteristic and that's not what I'm interested in. I want to prove it by defining an isomorphism between the two rings, but the one I thought was right didn't work. I'll explain what I did:

First, I noticed that, from previous exercises I did in my course that given that $R$ is boolean, then I know it's commutative and also that all of its ideals are principal. Since it only has principal ideals, it's a PID, and since it's a PID then it's a UFD. So I can select the finite family of irreducible elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in R$ sufficient to make the factorisation of any element of $R$.

Then, given any $x\in R$, then it must verify
$$x=a_1^{\beta_1}\cdots a_n^{\beta_n} \ \ , \ \ \beta_i\in\{0,1\}.$$
So I thought it would make sense to interpret these $\beta_i$ as the components of the equivalent of $x$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, to be said, I thought the right homomorphism would be

\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_2 & \to R \\
 (\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n) & \mapsto x=a_1^{\beta_1}\cdots a_n^{\beta_n},
\end{align*}

but if I'm not wrong, this is not an homomorphism (it does not verify the definition properties). Something about this feels so wrong to me, I was almost sure this was the right way to solve this problem. Where am I wrong? What can I do to solve this defining an isomorphism between both rings? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: I've just noticed my reasoning was wrong when I assumed that every ideal of $R$ being principal implied it being PID, since in order to be a PID it must be first an integral domain and that's not true in general, so it's just a principal ideal ring (not a domain). How can I approach this then?

Comment: Boolean rings are almost never integral domains, so trying to apply PID/UFD results isn't going to work.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, I think I must have confused the Principal ideal domain concept with the Principal ideal ring. Is that it? Is the ring then a unique factorisation ring if that's even a thing? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @DanielSchepler So all my reasoning about finding the factorisation of each element isn't valid? How can I define the sisomorphism then?

Comment: As far as I know, the usual argument would be in terms of atoms of the boolean ring: if a finite boolean ring has atoms $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ then one direction is $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_i$.  The other direction takes $b$ to the sequence whose $i$th element is 1 if $b \cdot a_i = a_i$ or 0 if $b \cdot a_i = 0$.  There's still a significant amount of work left to show the two maps are inverses.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh, if you're talking about that edit I did, it was a mistake, I didn't notice. I'm sorry.